# Rvm hangs when installing 'requirements'

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I installed Xcode command line tools at `/usr/bin/xcode-select` and `/usr/bin/usr/bin/xcodebuild`. When I run:

```
bash-3.2$ `rvm requirements`
```

it doesn't get past `Checking requirements for osx.` and stays on that line until I hit <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>C</kbd>. When I remove xcodebuild by running

```
rm -rf /usr/bin/usr/bin/xcodebuild
```

it proceeds to

```
Installing requirements for osx.
Error: Can't run /usr/bin/usr/bin/xcodebuild (no such file).
Already up-to-date.
Installing required packages: gcc46, libyaml, readline, openssl........
```

Can someone suggest ways to debug this?

Comment: What happens when you run `rvm requirements --debug`?

Comment: Rule #1: Don't ever delete anything, EVER.

Answer (score 0):

```
bash-3.2$
```

??  That looks like the postgres prompt to me.  You should be at a prompt like:

```
~/rails_projects/my_app$
```

Try typing:

```
bash-3.2$ exit
```

to get back to a prompt you can recognize.

Comment: or root prompt. either way - not the one you should be in

Comment: @MichaelSzyndel, Yeah I was looking up exactly what that prompt is after I posted, and apparently it's the default prompt in a bash shell.  The only time I see that prompt is when I su to the postgres user when I need to do something with the postgres db.

Comment: or `sudo su` which I guess OP did.

Comment: Okay, then rule #2: Don't ever use sudo with rvm.

Comment: By default xcode-select and xcodebuild are installed in /usr/bin but rvm requirements wants xcodebuild to be at $XCODE_PATH/usr/bin. So thats why I linked xcodebuild from /usr/bin/usr/bin. But this caused the hang.

Comment: Can you at least post the version of OSX you are using and what type of rvm installation you attempted?

Comment: OS Version 10.8 and RVM 1.22.3 and Xcode command line tools version 2003. Thanks!